# How do I model a Student-Class Relationship in grails ORM? Many-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate, grails, many-to-many, relational-database, grails-orm

This is what I have

```
class Student {
     static hasMany = class: Class
     static belongsTo = Class
}

class Class {
     static hasMany = student: Student 
}
```

I want to prevent any cascade deletion. Incase a class is deleted, the student shouldnt be even though they "belong-to" the Class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leaving the original answer below for reference, but I'm pretty sure it was wrong.  Per the documentation I linked, "Many-to-many: only saves cascade from the "owner" to the "dependant", not deletes."

--Original answer below--

In this case, your Student does not actually 'belongsTo' a class.  The purpose of 'belongsTo' is for controlling cascading saves and deletes, and in this case it doesn't sound like you want that.

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

You can have many to many without a belongsTo.

Also just as a heads up: you're going to confuse yourself by having something called "Class".  This will go badly even if it works, which I don't really think it will.  That's a reserved word in Java and already exists as a java class.

Comment: Well, thank you! I will check it out. I am actually not creating an actual student-class relationship but my objects have a similar scenario.

Comment: That's good!  I was imagining some never-ending line of .getClass() and it wasn't pretty... :-)  Good luck with the project!

Comment: Hi daniel, do you have any pointers on how to create a many-to-many mapping without the belongsTo tag? most examples I find only always contain it.

Comment: You know, I actually just read the documentation a little closer and it says that on many-to-many, deletes don't cascade.  I'm going to update my original answer to note that, because I feel like I gave you bad info up front!

Comment: But to answer your other question: you don't HAVE to have a belongsTo.  You can just leave it off completely, and not cascade saves either.  Just make sure to save changes to the Student (or whatever) and changes to the Class because nothing will cascade because neither really owns the other at that point.